# Finding the highest product of thirteen consecutive digits of the given 1000 digit number

Tags: java

I've written a program to compute the answer. But there is one anomaly.

```
  public class thirteen {

    public thirteen() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a=new int[1000];
    String s="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        int i=0;
    int max=0;
    int product=0;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        a[i]=s.charAt(i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<996;i++)
    {
product=a[i]*a[i+1]*a[i+2]*a[i+3]*a[i+4]*a[i+5]*a[i+6]*a[i+7]*a[i+8]*a[i+9]*a[i+10]*a[i+11]*a[i+12];
        if(product>max)
            max=product;
    }
    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
    System.out.println(a[0]);
    }
```

I'm unable to figure out what is going wrong..

Surprisingly, i got the output as

2091384832
7
55

Comment: where are you computing the 13 digit product?

Comment: A side note: the second cycle should have the condition i < 986, not 996, isn't it?

Comment: It should be i<988. My bad.. I made a mistake while typing here..

Comment: @PradyothShandilya: No problem. I've just wrote it to make sure that's the correct way (and yeah, 988, not 986 :) )

Comment: All right.. thanks

Comment: @PradyothShandilya a less error-prone way to write it is `1000 - 13` (or `s.length() - 13`).

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm a rookie to programming.. so, why is 1000-13 better?

Comment: Because it is expressive: you have 1000 characters, and you want to stop 13 characters before the end.

Answer (score 4):

You are computing the product of the char values, not the digits. As your output shows, the entry corresponding to `'7'` is 55, not 7.

Instead of

```
s.charAt(i)
```

use

```
Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i))
```

---

Also, the largest product you might encounter is `9^13 > 8^12 = 2^36 > Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So you need to make `product` a `long` instead of an `int`; and you should make `a` a `long[]`, so that the intermediate multiplications are `long` too.

Comment: Good catch on the overflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to be casting the characters into `int` since that can become expensive if done so many times. Knowing that character 0 is code 48 we simply need to substract 48 from the code to know the `int`.

That said, you'll be overflowing if you use `int` (in favor of `long`) as pointed out in other answers and you don't need to overcomplicate this task. You can walk the string in a chunk of 13 and get the result like this.

[I've set up a demo](https://repl.it/CVuS) for you to test the console output if needed.

```
String s = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

//This will be overriden inside the loop
long currentMax = 1;
String winningSequence = "";

//Iterate in chunks for 13
for(int i=13;i<s.length();i++){
    long challengerTotal = 1;
    String challengerString = s.substring(i-13,i);

    //Less expensive than parsing
    for(char c : challengerString.toCharArray()) {
        challengerTotal *= ((int)c)-48;
    }

    //System.out.println("testing: "+challengerString+" adds to: "+challengerTotal);
    if(currentMax < challengerTotal){
        winningSequence = challengerString;
        currentMax = challengerTotal;
    }
}
//Output de max
System.out.println(winningSequence+" wins with a total of: "+currentMax);
```

#### Note

In the rare event that all the possibilities contain a 0, the output will be wrong, so you might want to check if it, since if it's 1, it's probably 0.